# BeautifulSoup find_all() is returning empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm very new on the programming. Currently, I'm learning Python with Udemy course. I'm using Windows 10 OS and I'm using VS Code with Anaconda interpreter: [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAV48.jpg)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://yellowpages.com.tr/ara?q=ankara"

response = requests.get(url)

html_content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

print(soup.find_all("a"))
```

I wrote this code to attract all "a" caracters in website. However, when I want to run this code, It returns an empty list:

output:

```
[]
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please post the url and the content you wish to extract

Comment: Nothing will happen if you post a link.  And why did you post the version of Python you are using as an image?

Comment: Okay, I sent the link. I sent my Python version because I do not know if it is necessary or not necessary.

Comment: It's a javascript based website. You are better off using selenium

Comment: Okay thank you so much. But in my Python course, teacher ran the code which I posted and It worked without any problems. I didn't understand this situation.

Comment: @quinn Can you post the udemy course url?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is not links at the url you are parsing, I have tried with one that has urls and it works fine

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/optimizing-audio-files-for-speech-to-text?hl=it"
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

print(soup.find_all("a"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your code and It worked. But in my Python course, teacher tried the code which I posted and It worked.

Comment: But if I download the site using `curl`, they aren't there. The web site is doing something with JavaScript to load them, but I'm not sure how it's making it appear in the source. I don't see `document.write` anywhere.

Comment: well javascript can do absolutely anything so 'document.write' does not need to be there.